# ¿Es posible ocultar los métodos de una clase padre en una clase 'tercera'?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, drag-and-drop

Estoy construyendo una clase para manejar (y simplificar) el arrastre de controles en mi proyecto en C#. (Si, mi proyecto requiere si o si el arrastre de controles)

Mi clase se llama `Drag` (arrastrar en inglés) y debe extender obligatoriamente de `Form` por como está construida.

```
public class Drag : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    //Mi código
}
```

Anteriormente habia escrito esta clase y si, funciona perfectamente, pero ahora la estoy modificando para reducir la cantidad de código...

La clase `Drag` usa varios métodos y eventos de la clase `Form` que convierte en suyos, por eso `Drag` extiende de `Form`. El problema es que al crear un objeto de la clase `Drag` y acceder a sus métodos, me salen también los métodos de la clase `Form`, y eso es lo que quiero evitar.

En resumen,

> ¿Es posible que mi clase `Drag` extienda de la clase `Form`, pero que al instanciar `Drag` solo se usen los métodos exclusivos de `Drag` y no los de `Form`?
>
> Algo así como si `Drag` no extendiera de `Form` y que la herencia de los métodos y propiedades de `Form` solo funcione dentro de `Drag`.

De antemano, muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: No. Form no esta pensado para eso, y como no la hiciste vos, si sus metodos son publicos, seran publicos para todos sus hijos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el modificador `new` en la clase derivada para ocultar el método de la clase base y usar tu implementación. Te paso un ejemplo.

```
public class BaseC
{
    public int x;
    public void Invoke() { }
}
public class DerivedC : BaseC
{
    new public void Invoke() { }
}
```

Comment: Ya conozco ese metodo de ocultar metodos mediante el uso de la palabra clave new, pero haciendolo asi deberia hacerlo metodo por metodo y `Form` tiene muchos

Comment: La capacidad de usar `Drag And Drop` la proporciona la clase `Control`. A mi modo de ver y siento decirtelo si necesitas ocultar muchos miembros, es que el diseño de tu clase no es del todo correcto. Puedes mostrar algo de código que llevas implementado?